# Example of a pointwise convergent functional sequence that is not compactly convergent.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, examples-counterexamples

I'm looking for an example of a pointwisely convergent functional sequence $\{f_n\}_{n \geq 0}$ (where $f_n:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$) that is not compactly convergent.

I'm not sure if it is even possible since all of the sequences I come up with are at least compactly convergent if if they are pointwisely convergent:

1. $f_n(x)=\dfrac{x}{n}$ is not uniformly convergent, but it is compactly convergent.
2. $f_n(x)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{e^x}{e^k}$ doesn't fit my conditions as well.

Could you please give me a hint how I can get such a sequence?

Comment: A triangle of height $1$ with base $\bigl[0, \frac{2}{n}\bigr]$.

Comment: Take $f_n(x)=\chi_{[0,1)}\cdot x^n$. $(f_n)$ converges pointwise to $0$ but does not converge uniformly on the compact set $[0,1]$.

Comment: @DavidMitra, I cannot understand your notation. What is $\chi_{[0,1)}$ and $(f_n)$?

Comment: $\chi_A$ is the function taking value $1$ on $A$ and $0$ otherwise; so, $f_n(x)=\cases{ x^n, &$x\in[0,1)$\cr 0, & otherwise }$. I usually denote sequences with parentheses $(f_n)=\{ f_n\}_{n\ge0}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take odd $f_n$s with

$$f_n(x) =
    \begin{cases}
        nx, & \text{if $0\le x < 1/n$} \\
        2-nx, & \text{if $1/n\le x \le 2/n$.} \\
        0, & \text{if x > 2/n}
    \end{cases}$$

$f_n(x)\to 0$ pointwisely, since for any $x$ there is some $N_x$ that $x\in[-2/n,2/n]^c$ (namely $f_n(x)=0$) for any $n\ge N_x$. However the convergence is not compactly since $\max_{|x|\le1}|f_n(x)| = 1$ for any natural $n$.

Comment: and what if $x < 0$?

Comment: $f_n$s are odd, that is $f(-x)=-f(x)$. Or they could be even, $f(-x)=f(x)$, it does not metter.